# how do i list remote print queues in aix?

Tags: printing, aix

So lpstat returns all print queues.  What is a quick way to determine which of the print queues are remote and which are local?

Answer (score 1):

From [`man` page for `lpstat`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/lpstat.htm):

> The display generated by the lpstat command contains two entries for
>   remote queues. The first entry contains the client's local queue and
>   local device name and its status information. The second entry
>   contains the client's local queue name followed by the remote queue
>   name.

This should allow you to identify which queue is local, and which remote.